# Android Bidrectional Communication for few data: Wifi direct vs. Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, wifi, nfc

We would like to create a bidrectional communication between two Android devices.The process will be initiated by NFC. But because NFC just works one way we need to create a communication channel, either via Bluetooth or via Wifi direct. 
It will just be about 10 kb of data that will be transferred in total.

The process should work like this:

1. Android Device AD_1 uses NFC to push data to Android Device AD_2
2. AD_2 uses the received data to create a secure communication channel to AD_1
3. The Communication Channel is used to transmit about 10 kb of data back and forth

What communication channel to you recommend for Step 2: Wifi direct or Bluetooth?

Because it will just be so little data, it shouldnt be about the speed/throughput/speed of the connection, but instead about the connection setup time.

Comment: Transfering 10kb over NFC will take roughly 5 seconds. Why don't you just transfer with NFC?

Comment: @NilsPipenbrinck You can push data via NFC to another smartphone, however as far as I know it is not possible to send data back. The user would have to pull the devices apart and put them together a second time, which would not be convenient. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648149/bi-directional-android-beam

Answer (score 0):

Wi-Fi direct it's best for connection setup time, with bluetooth you must pair the devices which is not so fast because of, by standard, bluethooth visibility is set to hidden by default con Android and most people forget about it.
Remember also that bluethooth is expensive for smartphone battery.